# Facebook/Messenger in desktop doesn't show any recent messages after a limit and then only shows group messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

This behavior is quite peculiar. After a certain number of messages, no recent messages appear anymore and all the rest of the messages are just group messages.

[image]

What I have tried to solve this-

1. Removed site data, deleted cookies
2. Removed all extension
3. Tried a different browser (Firefox and a chromium browser)
4. Used the desktop messenger app

But the problem still persists! It is either some kind of network issue or the problem is with Facebook, because I listed every possible solution.

Answer (score -1):

Sir my sending Sms is block i don't know how to happen and know how send a rong sms to unknown propel i avoid to do this  please this account sms very important For my femly so please unlock  my sms on  FB messenger thanks you  Facebook team[image]